QGenericMatrix debugging shows the same column values

The memory address value has been checked and is correct, but the debug shows the problem.
Why is it showing the same memory address?
I want to see detailed information about the entire matrix value. Can I modify this display column somewhere?
Development environment ↓↓↓：
QtCreator 14.0.1
Windows11
Qt 6.5.3
MSVC 2019
